# Why do we express the liminf of an event using uion and intersections?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Why do we take the liminf of an event to be:

$\liminf_{n}A_n=\bigcup^{\infty}_{n=1}\bigcap_{k\geq n}A_k$

We know that $B_n = \bigcap_{k\geq n}A_k $ are increasing sets, ie $B_n\subseteq B_{n+1}$. So why do we still take the union when only the tail matters?

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \bigcap_{k\geq n}A_k \neq \bigcup^{\infty}_{n=1}\bigcap_{k\geq n}A_k$

Answer (score 1):

Because that's how the limit of a sequence of increasing sets is defined. It is the union. Indeed only the tail matters, but there's no final set to call the limit. That limit set is simply the union of all the tails.

When you write
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \bigcap_{k\geq n} A_k$$
this has no independent meaning. The way you define it is by taking the union.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $A = \bigcup^{\infty}_{n=1} A_n$.

Then $$\bigcup^{\infty}_{n=1}\bigcap_{k\geq n}A_k = \{a \in A|\exists n \in \mathbb{N} \forall k > n \text{ } a\in A_k\}$$

and

$$\bigcap_{k = n}^{\infty}A_k = \{a \in A|\forall k > n \text{ } a\in A_k\}\text{, where } n \text{ is given}$$

Now you can easily see, that those sets are not the same in general (despite allots of the second type are contained in the set of the first type as subsets)